# Scope Variables Are Empty in the Click Function From ng-Dialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is a menu:

```
 <li><a href="#" class="cbp-tm-icon-cog" ng-click="save_session()">Save Current Session</a></li>
```

on click save_session will be called:

```
 $scope.save_session = function () {
console.log($scope.opportunityname);
                $scope.opp_name_to_save = $scope.opportunity_name;
                ngDialog.open({ template: 'open_dialog_save_session', scope: $scope 

        };
```

Here I am getting opportunityname in console.log.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="open_dialog_save_session">
    <div id="open_dialog_save_session_pane" ng-controller="Opportunity_Controller" style="width:300px" ng-class="cbp-mc-column">

        <input type="text" ng-model="opp_name_to_save" class="editor-field" id="opportunity_session_name" style="width:185px;height:35px" ng-class="cbp-mc-form" />
        <input id="btn_opportunity_save" type="button" ng-click="save_current_session()" style="margin-left:10px;height:35px;width:90px" value="Save Session"/>

    </div>
</script>
```

Save current session is as follow:

```
 $scope.save_current_session = function () {

       console.log($scope.opportunityname);
}
```

Here I am getting opportnunityname as empty.

Comment: You need to provide more of a description of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have a menu link. On click of the menu link, I am populating an ng-Dialog.The ngdialog has a button. On click of the button..I am calling a function..in that function I am getting some variables from scope and sending to the server side using http...So I am not able to get hold of the scope variables in the function which I am calling on click of the button in the templete.

Comment: you have $scope.opportunity_name, but consoling console.log($scope.opportunityname)

Comment: sorry that was a typo..but I am using correct variable name

Comment: You still need to provide more code for people to be able to help.